# How to play an encrypted remote audio/video file when streaming on the fly

Tags: android, encryption, aes, exoplayer

I need to play an encrypted remote audio file on the fly using ExoPlayer. I've implemented a custom `DataSource` to handle `read()` and `open()` methods. It works fine when the audio file starts from the beginning (position = 0) but when it starts from some other position or when I seek the audio, the cipher breaks down and crops the file resulting in ExoPlayer error.
Through the search, I realized that the problem refers to the `skip()` method of CipherInputStream which should get overridden regarding the encryption algorithm.
Having the above conditions, how should I implement the `skip()` method?

Here is `HttpCipherEncryptedDataSource` as the custom `DataSource`:

```
class HttpCipherEncryptedDataSource(
    private val key: ByteArray,
) : DataSource {

    private val connectionMaker = HttpConnectionMaker()

    private var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    private var cipherInputStream: CipherHttpInputStream? = null
    private var dataSpec: DataSpec? = null
    private var uri: Uri? = null

    private var bytesToRead: Long = 0
    private var bytesRead: Long = 0
    private var isOpen = false

    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        this.uri = dataSpec.uri
        this.dataSpec = dataSpec

        // make server connection
        connection = connectionMaker.make(dataSpec)
        val responseCode = connection!!.responseCode
        val responseMessage = connection!!.responseMessage

        // Check for a valid response code.
        if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode > 299) {
            val headers = connection!!.headerFields
            if (responseCode == 416) {
                val documentSize =
                    HttpUtil.getDocumentSize(connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE))
                if (dataSpec.position == documentSize) {
                    isOpen = true
                    return if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) dataSpec.length else 0
                }
            }
            val errorStream = connection!!.errorStream
            val errorResponseBody = try {
                if (errorStream != null) Util.toByteArray(errorStream) else Util.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Util.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
            }
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            val cause: IOException? =
                if (responseCode == 416) DataSourceException(PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_READ_POSITION_OUT_OF_RANGE) else null
            throw InvalidResponseCodeException(
                responseCode, responseMessage, cause, headers, dataSpec, errorResponseBody
            )
        }

        // calculate current position
        val bytesToSkip =
            if (responseCode == 200 && dataSpec.position != 0L) dataSpec.position else 0

        // Determine the length of the data to be read, after skipping.
        val isCompressed = isCompressed(connection!!)
        if (!isCompressed) {
            bytesToRead = if (dataSpec.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                dataSpec.length
            } else {
                val contentLength = HttpUtil.getContentLength(
                    connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH),
                    connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE)
                )
                if (contentLength != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) contentLength - bytesToSkip else C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
            }
        } else {
            // Gzip is enabled. If the server opts to use gzip then the content length in the response
            // will be that of the compressed data, which isn't what we want. Always use the dataSpec
            // length in this case.
            bytesToRead = dataSpec.length
        }

        var encryptedStream: InputStream?
        try {
            encryptedStream = connection!!.inputStream
            if (isCompressed) {
                encryptedStream = GZIPInputStream(encryptedStream)
            }
            setupCipherInputStream(encryptedStream!!)
            cipherInputStream?.forceSkip(dataSpec.position)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            throw HttpDataSourceException(
                e,
                dataSpec,
                PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_UNSPECIFIED,
                HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
            )
        }
        isOpen = true
        return bytesToRead
    }

    private fun setupCipherInputStream(encryptedFileStream: InputStream) {
        val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(
            key,
            "AES"
        )
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
            "AES/ECB/PCSK5Padding"
        )
        cipherInputStream = CipherHttpInputStream(
            encryptedFileStream,
            cipher,
            keySpec
        )
    }

    private fun isCompressed(connection: HttpURLConnection): Boolean {
        val contentEncoding = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding")
        return "gzip".equals(contentEncoding, ignoreCase = true)
    }

    @Throws(HttpDataSourceException::class)
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int): Int {
        try {
            var readLength = length
            if (readLength == 0) {
                return 0
            }
            if (bytesToRead != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                val bytesRemaining: Long = bytesToRead - bytesRead
                if (bytesRemaining == 0L) {
                    return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
                }
                readLength = Math.min(readLength.toLong(), bytesRemaining).toInt()
            }

            val read = Util.castNonNull<InputStream>(cipherInputStream).read(buffer, offset, readLength)
            if (read == -1) {
                return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
            }

            bytesRead += read.toLong()
            return read
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw HttpDataSourceException.createForIOException(
                e, Util.castNonNull(dataSpec), HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_READ
            )
        }
    }

    override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener) {}

    override fun getUri() = uri

    @Throws(HttpDataSourceException::class)
    override fun close() {
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = this.cipherInputStream
            if (inputStream != null) {
                val bytesRemaining =
                    if (bytesToRead == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong() else bytesToRead - bytesRead
                maybeTerminateInputStream(connection, bytesRemaining)
                try {
                    inputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    throw HttpDataSourceException(
                        e,
                        Util.castNonNull(dataSpec),
                        PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_UNSPECIFIED,
                        HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_CLOSE
                    )
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cipherInputStream = null
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            if (isOpen) {
                isOpen = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun maybeTerminateInputStream(connection: HttpURLConnection?, bytesRemaining: Long) {
        if (connection == null || Util.SDK_INT < 19 || Util.SDK_INT > 20) {
            return
        }
        try {
            val inputStream = connection.inputStream
            if (bytesRemaining == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                // If the input stream has already ended, do nothing. The socket may be re-used.
                if (inputStream.read() == -1) {
                    return
                }
            } else if (bytesRemaining <= MAX_BYTES_TO_DRAIN) {
                // There isn't much data left. Prefer to allow it to drain, which may allow the socket to be
                // re-used.
                return
            }
            val className = inputStream.javaClass.name
            if ("com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport\$ChunkedInputStream" == className
                || ("com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport\$FixedLengthInputStream"
                        == className)
            ) {
                val superclass: Class<in InputStream>? = inputStream.javaClass.superclass
                val unexpectedEndOfInput =
                    Assertions.checkNotNull(superclass).getDeclaredMethod("unexpectedEndOfInput")
                unexpectedEndOfInput.isAccessible = true
                unexpectedEndOfInput.invoke(inputStream)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // If an IOException then the connection didn't ever have an input stream, or it was closed
            // already. If another type of exception then something went wrong, most likely the device
            // isn't using okhttp.
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_BYTES_TO_DRAIN: Long = 2048
    }
}
```

and also `CipherHttpInputStream` to handle `skip` method:

```
class CipherHttpInputStream(
    private val upstream: InputStream,
    private val cipher: Cipher,
    private val secretKeySpec: SecretKeySpec,
) : CipherInputStream(upstream, cipher) {

    private val MAX_SKIP_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048

    fun forceSkip(bytesToSkip: Long) {
        var remaining: Long = bytesToSkip
        var nr: Int

        if (bytesToSkip <= 0) {
            return
        }
        val size = Math.min(MAX_SKIP_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong(), remaining).toInt()
        val skipBuffer = ByteArray(size)
        initCipher()
        while (remaining > 0) {
            nr = upstream.read(skipBuffer, 0, Math.min(size.toLong(), remaining).toInt())
            if (nr < 0) {
                break
            }
            remaining -= nr.toLong()
        }
    }

    private fun initCipher() {
        cipher.init(
            Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
            secretKeySpec,
        )
    }

    override fun available(): Int {
        return upstream.available()
    }

}
```

Comment: Your own `skip()` method is no better. It reads and counts input bytes, not output bytes. Ditto your `available()` method. `CipherInputStream.skip()` only skips up to the number of available bytes. You should just issue enough `read()`s on the *cipher* stream to get to the offset you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching and debugging, eventually I came up with the problem. Since this DataSource is responsible for playing a remote encrypted Audio file, every time that `open()` is called (particularly when seeking), a new `InputStream` is instantiated wrapping the file streams starting at the exact position in which ExoPlayer is supposed to start. So there is no need to use the `skip()` method in this scenario. However, the bug still refers back to the starting position of the file. As far as CipherInputStream reads the upstream block by block(`cipher.blockSize`) if the starting position is not divisible by `cipher.blockSize`, it will result in `ERROR_CODE_PARSING_CONTAINER_MALFORMED` ExoPlayer error.
To tackle this obstacle, I wrote the following function to calculate the appropriate starting position regarding the cipher block size and store it inside a new `dataSpec`.

Here is the function:

```
// check if the new position divided by cipher.blockSize
// results in zero. If not truncate the remaining.
private fun modifyBytesBlocks(dataSpec: DataSpec): DataSpec {
    val bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock = dataSpec.position % cipher.blockSize
    var bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart =
        dataSpec.position - bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock - cipher.blockSize
    if (bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart < 0) bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart = 0

    return DataSpec(
        dataSpec.uri,
        dataSpec.httpMethod,
        dataSpec.httpBody,
        bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart,
        bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart,
        dataSpec.length,
        dataSpec.key,
        dataSpec.flags,
        dataSpec.httpRequestHeaders
    )
}
```

which should be used at the beginning of `open`, replacing the original `dataSpec`. Here is the whole working custom `DataSource` source:

```
class HttpCipherEncryptedDataSource(key: ByteArray) : DataSource {

    private val connectionMaker = HttpConnectionMaker()
    private val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(
        key,
        "AES"
    )
   private val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
        "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"
    )

    private var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    private var cipherInputStream: CipherHttpInputStream? = null
    private var updatedDataSpec: DataSpec? = null
    private var uri: Uri? = null

    private var bytesToRead: Long = 0
    private var bytesRead: Long = 0
    private var isOpen = false

    override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {
        bytesRead = 0
        bytesToRead = 0
        this.uri = dataSpec.uri
        this.updatedDataSpec = modifyBytesBlocks(dataSpec)
        val responseCode: Int
        val responseMessage: String
        try {
            // make server connection
            connection = connectionMaker.make(updatedDataSpec!!)
             responseCode = connection!!.responseCode
             responseMessage = connection!!.responseMessage
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            throw HttpDataSourceException.createForIOException(
                e, dataSpec, HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
            )
        }
        // Check for a valid response code.
        if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode > 299) {
            val headers = connection!!.headerFields
            if (responseCode == 416) {
                val documentSize =
                    HttpUtil.getDocumentSize(connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE))
                if (updatedDataSpec!!.position == documentSize) {
                    isOpen = true
                    return if (updatedDataSpec!!.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) updatedDataSpec!!.length else 0
                }
            }
            val errorStream = connection!!.errorStream
            val errorResponseBody = try {
                if (errorStream != null) Util.toByteArray(errorStream) else Util.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Util.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
            }
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            val cause: IOException? =
                if (responseCode == 416) DataSourceException(PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_READ_POSITION_OUT_OF_RANGE) else null
            throw InvalidResponseCodeException(
                responseCode, responseMessage, cause, headers, updatedDataSpec!!, errorResponseBody
            )
        }

        // calculate current position
        val bytesToSkip =
            if (responseCode == 200 && updatedDataSpec!!.position != 0L) updatedDataSpec!!.position else 0

        // Determine the length of the data to be read, after skipping.
        val isCompressed = isCompressed(connection!!)
        if (!isCompressed) {
            bytesToRead = if (updatedDataSpec!!.length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                updatedDataSpec!!.length
            } else {
                val contentLength = HttpUtil.getContentLength(
                    connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH),
                    connection!!.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE)
                )
                if (contentLength != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) contentLength - bytesToSkip else C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()
            }
        } else {
            // Gzip is enabled. If the server opts to use gzip then the content length in the response
            // will be that of the compressed data, which isn't what we want. Always use the dataSpec
            // length in this case.
            bytesToRead = updatedDataSpec!!.length
        }

        var encryptedStream: InputStream?
        try {
            encryptedStream = connection!!.inputStream
            if (isCompressed) {
                encryptedStream = GZIPInputStream(encryptedStream)
            }
            setupCipherInputStream(encryptedStream!!)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            throw HttpDataSourceException(
                e,
                updatedDataSpec!!,
                PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_UNSPECIFIED,
                HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
            )
        }
        isOpen = true
        return bytesToRead
    }

    // check if the new position divided by cipher.blockSize
    // results in zero. If not truncate the remaining.
    private fun modifyBytesBlocks(dataSpec: DataSpec): DataSpec {
        val bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock = dataSpec.position % cipher.blockSize
        var bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart =
            dataSpec.position - bytesSinceStartOfCurrentBlock - cipher.blockSize
        if (bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart < 0) bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart = 0

        return DataSpec(
            dataSpec.uri,
            dataSpec.httpMethod,
            dataSpec.httpBody,
            bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart,
            bytesUntilPreviousBlockStart,
            dataSpec.length,
            dataSpec.key,
            dataSpec.flags,
            dataSpec.httpRequestHeaders
        )
    }

    private fun setupCipherInputStream(encryptedFileStream: InputStream) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec)
        cipherInputStream = CipherHttpInputStream(
            encryptedFileStream,
            cipher
        )
    }

    private fun isCompressed(connection: HttpURLConnection): Boolean {
        val contentEncoding = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding")
        return "gzip".equals(contentEncoding, ignoreCase = true)
    }

    @Throws(HttpDataSourceException::class)
    override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, length: Int): Int {
        try {
            var readLength = length
            if (readLength == 0) {
                return 0
            }
            if (bytesToRead != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                val bytesRemaining: Long = bytesToRead - bytesRead
                if (bytesRemaining == 0L) {
                    return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
                }
                readLength = Math.min(readLength.toLong(), bytesRemaining).toInt()
            }

            val read =
                Util.castNonNull<InputStream>(cipherInputStream).read(buffer, offset, readLength)
            if (read == -1) {
                return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
            }

            bytesRead += read.toLong()
            return read
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw HttpDataSourceException.createForIOException(
                e, Util.castNonNull(updatedDataSpec), HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_READ
            )
        }
    }

    override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener) {}

    override fun getUri() = uri

    @Throws(HttpDataSourceException::class)
    override fun close() {
        try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = this.cipherInputStream
            if (inputStream != null) {
                val bytesRemaining =
                    if (bytesToRead == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong() else bytesToRead - bytesRead
                maybeTerminateInputStream(connection, bytesRemaining)
                try {
                    inputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    throw HttpDataSourceException(
                        e,
                        Util.castNonNull(updatedDataSpec),
                        PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_UNSPECIFIED,
                        HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_CLOSE
                    )
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cipherInputStream = null
            connectionMaker.closeConnection()
            if (isOpen) {
                isOpen = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun maybeTerminateInputStream(connection: HttpURLConnection?, bytesRemaining: Long) {
        if (connection == null || Util.SDK_INT < 19 || Util.SDK_INT > 20) {
            return
        }
        try {
            val inputStream = connection.inputStream
            if (bytesRemaining == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                // If the input stream has already ended, do nothing. The socket may be re-used.
                if (inputStream.read() == -1) {
                    return
                }
            } else if (bytesRemaining <= MAX_BYTES_TO_DRAIN) {
                // There isn't much data left. Prefer to allow it to drain, which may allow the socket to be
                // re-used.
                return
            }
            val className = inputStream.javaClass.name
            if ("com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport\$ChunkedInputStream" == className
                || ("com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport\$FixedLengthInputStream"
                        == className)
            ) {
                val superclass: Class<in InputStream>? = inputStream.javaClass.superclass
                val unexpectedEndOfInput =
                    Assertions.checkNotNull(superclass).getDeclaredMethod("unexpectedEndOfInput")
                unexpectedEndOfInput.isAccessible = true
                unexpectedEndOfInput.invoke(inputStream)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // If an IOException then the connection didn't ever have an input stream, or it was closed
            // already. If another type of exception then something went wrong, most likely the device
            // isn't using okhttp.
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    class HttpConnectionMaker {

        private var defaultRequestProperties: HttpDataSource.RequestProperties? = null
        private var requestProperties = HttpDataSource.RequestProperties()
        private var readTimeoutMillis = DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS
        private var connectTimeoutMillis = DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS
        private var allowCrossProtocolRedirects = false
        private var keepPostFor302Redirects = false
        private var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
        private var userAgent: String? = null

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun make(dataSpec: DataSpec): HttpURLConnection {
            var url = URL(dataSpec.uri.toString())
            var httpMethod: @DataSpec.HttpMethod Int = dataSpec.httpMethod
            var httpBody = dataSpec.httpBody
            val position = dataSpec.position
            val length = dataSpec.length
            val allowGzip = dataSpec.isFlagSet(DataSpec.FLAG_ALLOW_GZIP)
            if (!allowCrossProtocolRedirects && !keepPostFor302Redirects) {
                // HttpURLConnection disallows cross-protocol redirects, but otherwise performs redirection
                // automatically. This is the behavior we want, so use it.
                return make(
                    url,
                    httpMethod,
                    httpBody,
                    position,
                    length,
                    allowGzip,  /* followRedirects= */
                    true,
                    dataSpec.httpRequestHeaders
                )
            }

            // We need to handle redirects ourselves to allow cross-protocol redirects or to keep the POST
            // request method for 302.
            var redirectCount = 0
            while (redirectCount++ <= MAX_REDIRECTS) {
                connection = make(
                    url,
                    httpMethod,
                    httpBody,
                    position,
                    length,
                    allowGzip,  /* followRedirects= */
                    false,
                    dataSpec.httpRequestHeaders
                )
                val responseCode = connection?.responseCode
                val location = connection?.getHeaderField("Location")
                if ((httpMethod == DataSpec.HTTP_METHOD_GET || httpMethod == DataSpec.HTTP_METHOD_HEAD)
                    && (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MULT_CHOICE
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER
                            || responseCode == HTTP_STATUS_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
                            || responseCode == HTTP_STATUS_PERMANENT_REDIRECT)
                ) {
                    connection?.disconnect()
                    url = handleRedirect(url, location, dataSpec)
                } else if (httpMethod == DataSpec.HTTP_METHOD_POST
                    && (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MULT_CHOICE
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                            || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                ) {
                    connection?.disconnect()
                    val shouldKeepPost =
                        keepPostFor302Redirects && responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    if (!shouldKeepPost) {
                        // POST request follows the redirect and is transformed into a GET request.
                        httpMethod = DataSpec.HTTP_METHOD_GET
                        httpBody = null
                    }
                    url = handleRedirect(url, location, dataSpec)
                } else {
                    return connection!!
                }
            }
            throw HttpDataSourceException(
                NoRouteToHostException("Too many redirects: $redirectCount"),
                dataSpec,
                PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_NETWORK_CONNECTION_FAILED,
                HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
            )
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun make(
            url: URL,
            httpMethod: @DataSpec.HttpMethod Int,
            httpBody: ByteArray?,
            position: Long,
            length: Long,
            allowGzip: Boolean,
            followRedirects: Boolean,
            requestParameters: Map<String, String>,
        ): HttpURLConnection {
            val connection = openConnection(url)
            connection.connectTimeout = connectTimeoutMillis
            connection.readTimeout = readTimeoutMillis
            val requestHeaders: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            if (defaultRequestProperties != null) {
                requestHeaders.putAll(defaultRequestProperties!!.snapshot)
            }
            requestHeaders.putAll(requestProperties.snapshot)
            requestHeaders.putAll(requestParameters)
            for ((key, value) in requestHeaders) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(key, value)
            }
            //header range
            val rangeHeader = buildRangeRequestHeader(position, length)
            if (rangeHeader != null) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.RANGE, rangeHeader)
            }
            if (userAgent != null) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, userAgent)
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING,
                if (allowGzip) "gzip" else "identity"
            )
            connection.instanceFollowRedirects = followRedirects
            connection.doOutput = httpBody != null
            connection.requestMethod = DataSpec.getStringForHttpMethod(httpMethod)
            if (httpBody != null) {
                connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(httpBody.size)
                connection.connect()
                val os = connection.outputStream
                os.write(httpBody)
                os.close()
            } else {
                connection.connect()
            }
            return connection
        }

        private fun buildRangeRequestHeader(position: Long, length: Long): String? {
            if (position == 0L && length == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                return null
            }
            val rangeValue = StringBuilder()
            rangeValue.append("bytes=")
            rangeValue.append(position)
            rangeValue.append("-")

            if (length != C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                rangeValue.append(position + length - 1)
            }
            return rangeValue.toString()
        }

        @VisibleForTesting
        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun openConnection(url: URL): HttpURLConnection {
            return url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        }

        @Throws(HttpDataSourceException::class)
        private fun handleRedirect(originalUrl: URL, location: String?, dataSpec: DataSpec): URL {
            if (location == null) {
                throw HttpDataSourceException(
                    "Null location redirect",
                    dataSpec,
                    PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_NETWORK_CONNECTION_FAILED,
                    HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
                )
            }
            // Form the new url.
            val url: URL = try {
                URL(originalUrl, location)
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                throw HttpDataSourceException(
                    e,
                    dataSpec,
                    PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_NETWORK_CONNECTION_FAILED,
                    HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
                )
            }

            // Check that the protocol of the new url is supported.
            val protocol = url.protocol
            if ("https" != protocol && "http" != protocol) {
                throw HttpDataSourceException(
                    "Unsupported protocol redirect: $protocol",
                    dataSpec,
                    PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_NETWORK_CONNECTION_FAILED,
                    HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
                )
            }
            if (!allowCrossProtocolRedirects && protocol != originalUrl.protocol) {
                throw HttpDataSourceException(
                    "Disallowed cross-protocol redirect ("
                            + originalUrl.protocol
                            + " to "
                            + protocol
                            + ")",
                    dataSpec,
                    PlaybackException.ERROR_CODE_IO_NETWORK_CONNECTION_FAILED,
                    HttpDataSourceException.TYPE_OPEN
                )
            }
            return url
        }

        fun closeConnection() {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection?.disconnect()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                connection = null
            }
        }

        companion object {
            private const val DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 8 * 1000

            /** The default read timeout, in milliseconds.  */
            private const val DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 8 * 1000

            private const val MAX_REDIRECTS = 20 // Same limit as okhttp.

            private const val HTTP_STATUS_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT = 307
            private const val HTTP_STATUS_PERMANENT_REDIRECT = 308
        }
    }

    class CipherHttpInputStream(
        private val upstream: InputStream,
        cipher: Cipher,
    ) : CipherInputStream(upstream, cipher) {

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun available(): Int {
            return upstream.available()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MAX_BYTES_TO_DRAIN: Long = 2048
    }
}
```